hot chocolate and automapper could not be translated when model contains collection
I have a resolver that returns an IQueryable from Entity Framework Core. When I return the EF Core entity directly, everything works fine. However, when I attempt to map the EF Core entity to my GraphQL model, the query fails to translate properly, specifically when the model contains a collection
When I make this request with the ProjectTo<Graphql.Models.Patient> it fails and I get the response:
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unexpected Execution Error",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "patients"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "message": "The LINQ expression 'p2 => new Session{ Token = p2.Token }\r\n' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.",
        "stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 lambdaExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateInternal(Expression expression, Boolean applyDefaultTypeMapping)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateProjection(Expression expression, Boolean applyDefaultTypeMapping)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)\r\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression conditionalExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)\r\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Translate(Expression expression)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()\r\n   at HotChocolate.DefaultAsyncEnumerableExecutable`1.ToListAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.ListPostProcessor`1.ToCompletionResultAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}

when i run it using the IQueryable directly i do get the excpected result:
{
  "data": {
    "patients": [
      {
        "user": {
          "address": {
            "street": "Elm St"
          },
          "sessions": [
            {
              "token": "token6"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "user": {
          "address": {
            "street": "Pine Rd"
          },
          "sessions": [
            {
              "token": "token9"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

and if i remove the List from my Graphql models (and also don't request it) it also works as expected
request query:
query {
  patients {
    user {
      address {
        street
      }
      sessions{
        token
      }
    }
  }
}

PatientRepository method
public IQueryable<Data.Table.Patient> GetPatientsQueryable()
{
    return Context.Patients.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
}

resolvers examples
[UseProjection]        
public async Task<IQueryable<Patient>> GetPatients([Service] IPatientRepository repository, [Service] IMapper Mapper)
{
    //DOES NOT WORK
    var dataModelQueryable = repository.GetPatientsQueryable();
    var graphqlModelQueryable = Mapper.ProjectTo<Patient>(dataModelQueryable);

    return graphqlModelQueryable;
}

[UseProjection]
public async Task<IQueryable<Data.Tables.Patient>> GetPatients([Service] IPatientRepository repository, [Service] IMapper Mapper)
{
    //WORKS
    var dataModelQueryable = repository.GetPatientsQueryable();
    return dataModelQueryable;
}

graphql models
namespace Api.GraphQL.Models
{
    public class Patient
    {
        public User User { get; set; }

        public BloodType BloodType { get; set; }

        public int Height { get; set; }

        public decimal Weight { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Api.GraphQL.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Bsn { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateOnly DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        //WHEN REMOVING THIS LIST BOTH METHODS WORK 
        public List<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Api.GraphQL.Models
{
    public class Session
    {
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    }
}


EF Core tables
namespace Data.Tables
{
    public class Patient
    {
        [Key, ForeignKey(nameof(User)), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int UserBsn { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public BloodType BloodType { get; set; }

        public required int Height { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(5,2)")]
        public required decimal Weight { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Data.Tables
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Bsn { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public required string? FirstName { get; set; }
        
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        
        [MaxLength(255)]
        public required string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateOnly DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; } 
    }
}

namespace Data.Tables
{
    public class Session
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(User))]
        public int UserBsn { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(128)]
        public required string Token { get; set; }

        public required DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    }
}

using AutoMapper;

namespace Api
{
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Mapping profile for AutoMapper (data tables to graphql models)
        /// </summary>
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Data.Tables.Patient, GraphQL.Models.Patient>();
            CreateMap<GraphQL.Models.Patient, Data.Tables.Patient>();

            CreateMap<Data.Tables.User, GraphQL.Models.User>();
            CreateMap<GraphQL.Models.User, Data.Tables.User>();

            CreateMap<Data.Tables.Session, GraphQL.Models.Session>();
            CreateMap<GraphQL.Models.Session, Data.Tables.Session>();

            CreateMap<Data.Tables.Address, GraphQL.Models.Address>();
            CreateMap<GraphQL.Models.Address, Data.Tables.Address>();
        }
    }
}


EXTRA:
when logging the compilation with EntityFramework it looks the same for how the session is mapped
but automapper gives the error and my own .Select doesn't
Own Select:
public async Task<IQueryable<Patient>> GetPatients2([Service] IPatientRepository repository, [Service] IMapper Mapper)
{

    var dataModelQueryable = repository.GetPatientsQueryable();
    var graphqlModelQueryable = dataModelQueryable.Select(dtoPatient => new GraphQL.Models.Patient()
    {
        BloodType = dtoPatient.BloodType,
        Height = dtoPatient.Height,
        User = new GraphQL.Models.User()
        {
            Bsn = dtoPatient.User.Bsn,
            Address = new GraphQL.Models.Address()
            {
                City = dtoPatient.User.Address.City,
                CountryOfResidence = dtoPatient.User.Address.CountryOfResidence,
                HouseNumber = dtoPatient.User.Address.HouseNumber,
                Id = dtoPatient.User.Address.Id,
                PostalCode = dtoPatient.User.Address.PostalCode,
                Province = dtoPatient.User.Address.PostalCode,
                Street = dtoPatient.User.Address.Street,
            },
            DateOfBirth = dtoPatient.User.DateOfBirth,
            FirstName = dtoPatient.User.FirstName,
            MiddleName = dtoPatient.User.MiddleName,
            LastName = dtoPatient.User.LastName,
            Sessions = dtoPatient.User.Sessions.Select(dtoSession => new GraphQL.Models.Session()
            {
                ExpirationDate = dtoSession.ExpirationDate,
                Token = dtoSession.Token,
            }).ToList()
        },
        Weight = dtoPatient.Weight
    });

    return graphqlModelQueryable;
}

dbug: 18/10/2024 20:20:43.318 CoreEventId.QueryCompilationStarting[10111] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query)
      Compiling query expression:
      'DbSet<Patient>()
          .AsNoTracking()
          .Select(dtoPatient => new Patient{
              BloodType = dtoPatient.BloodType,
              Height = dtoPatient.Height,
              User = new User{
                  Bsn = dtoPatient.User.Bsn,
                  Address = new Address{
                      City = dtoPatient.User.Address.City,
                      CountryOfResidence = dtoPatient.User.Address.CountryOfResidence,
                      HouseNumber = dtoPatient.User.Address.HouseNumber,
                      Id = dtoPatient.User.Address.Id,
                      PostalCode = dtoPatient.User.Address.PostalCode,
                      Province = dtoPatient.User.Address.PostalCode,
                      Street = dtoPatient.User.Address.Street
                  }
                  ,
                  DateOfBirth = dtoPatient.User.DateOfBirth,
                  FirstName = dtoPatient.User.FirstName,
                  MiddleName = dtoPatient.User.MiddleName,
                  LastName = dtoPatient.User.LastName,
                  Sessions = dtoPatient.User.Sessions
                      .Select(dtoSession => new Session{
                          ExpirationDate = dtoSession.ExpirationDate,
                          Token = dtoSession.Token
                      }
                      )
                      .ToList()
              }
              ,
              Weight = dtoPatient.Weight
          }
          )
          .Select(_s1 => new Patient{ User = _s1.User != null ? new User{
                  Address = _s1.User.Address != null ? new Address{ Street = _s1.User.Address.Street }
                   : null,
                  Sessions = _s1.User.Sessions
                      .Select(p2 => new Session{ Token = p2.Token }
                      )
                      .ToList()
              }
               : null }
          )'

Automapper:
      'DbSet<Patient>()
          .AsNoTracking()
          .Select(dtoPatient => new Patient{
              User = dtoPatient.User == null ? null : new User{
                  Bsn = dtoPatient.User.Bsn,
                  FirstName = dtoPatient.User.FirstName,
                  MiddleName = dtoPatient.User.MiddleName,
                  LastName = dtoPatient.User.LastName,
                  DateOfBirth = dtoPatient.User.DateOfBirth,
                  Sessions = dtoPatient.User.Sessions
                      .Select(dtoSession => new Session{
                          Token = dtoSession.Token,
                          ExpirationDate = dtoSession.ExpirationDate
                      }
                      )
                      .ToList(),
                  Address = dtoPatient.User.Address == null ? null : new Address{
                      Id = dtoPatient.User.Address.Id,
                      Street = dtoPatient.User.Address.Street,
                      HouseNumber = dtoPatient.User.Address.HouseNumber,
                      PostalCode = dtoPatient.User.Address.PostalCode,
                      City = dtoPatient.User.Address.City,
                      Province = dtoPatient.User.Address.Province,
                      CountryOfResidence = dtoPatient.User.Address.CountryOfResidence
                  }

              }
              ,
              BloodType = dtoPatient.BloodType,
              Height = dtoPatient.Height,
              Weight = dtoPatient.Weight
          }
          )
          .Select(_s1 => new Patient{ User = _s1.User != null ? new User{
                  Address = _s1.User.Address != null ? new Address{ Street = _s1.User.Address.Street }
                   : null,
                  Sessions = _s1.User.Sessions
                      .Select(p2 => new Session{ Token = p2.Token }
                      )
                      .ToList()
              }
               : null }
          )'

Pinpointed the problem to the null check dtoPatient.User == null ? null :  new GraphQL.Models.User()
when adding this to my own select it also gives the issue but I don't see what the collection has to do with this as it only fails when also requesting a field from the sessions collection

Sow your mapping configuration, also try project without Automapper, using Select 

@SvyatoslavDanyliv
Switching to .Select works, but I'd prefer to keep using AutoMapper (or a similar tool) to avoid writing these large conversion methods. any tips on that? i've also included to MappingProfile

Sorry, no. You have to analyse what Automapper is generated, it generates similar Select but looks like with some differences, maybe with null checks. In opposite I like to control mapping by myself.

For one thing you should be returning IQueryable<T> not Task<IQueryable<T>> with calls like this. There is no asynchronous element to these operations. Consumers of the IQuertable can still await the actual async executions. Nothing stands out, though I am a bit wary of controller methods or the like passing back IQueryable themselves. I would expect to see them return back async Task<IEnumerable<T>> and having them materialize the results with an await query.ToListAsync();

If you're sure you don't need the null checks, use DoNotAllowNull.

@StevePy changed it to return IQueryable, but why would I change it to Task<IEnumerable> reason for returning the IQueryable is so that I don't fetch everything from the database but only what is requested when calling the endpoint
why are you wary of the controller methods?

@LucianBargaoanu
changing it to DoNotAllowNull on all member of Patient does seem to fix the problem
CreateMap<Data.Tables.Patient, GraphQL.Models.Patient>().ForAllMembers(x => x.DoNotAllowNull());
but I'm not sure if I like that solution

only changing the user member to DoNotAllowNull also seems to fix the issue (instead of all members)
CreateMap<Data.Tables.Patient, GraphQL.Models.Patient>().ForMember(x => x.User, x => x.DoNotAllowNull());

If you're sure you don't need the null checks, use DoNotAllowNull.
That tells AM to skip null checking.
